# React-Native Fetch/Axios no statusText

Tags: react-native, fetch, axios

i have some issue with my react-native ajax calls using fetch or axios library. There is no way to get the http statusText on a failed Ajax call. The statusText property is always undefined.

A quick example here:

```
  axios.post(this._apiBasePath + url, data, {
            headers: this._header,
            timeout:5000,
            responseType: respType
        }).then(d => {
            res(d.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            if(err.response){
               console.log(err.response);
               // there is a status 401 but no statusText in err Object
            }
        });
```

Maybe you guys could help me?

[json of the error object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNQaZ.png)

(Tested in iOS and Android simulator)

(react 16.4.1 / react-native 0.55.4)

Comment: With axios, I believe it might be err.data.response?

Comment: data is null in the err object. I think it is only filled in the success case.

Comment: err.response.data / err.response.headers / err.response.status?

Comment: I updated the question and added a screenshot with the output of the console.log

Comment: You're not returning an error from the server, hence why data is null. I don't know what language/backend you're using but you could just return ['error' => 'message'] to display to the user?

Comment: If I did the same request directly from the browser (same backend) it returns the following (chrome debugger) : Status Code: 401 [] User 'test' could not be validated! Reason: User 'asd' was not found. So there is a returned statusText

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue with React-Native and `fetch` showing the `statusText` as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try the following code, you can call http in android,but only call https in IOS

```js
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            lists:[]
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch(url, {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
           this.setState({ lists: responseData.result });
        })
        .done();
    }
```

Comment: I have no problem to get data from my backend. Also with http (in simulator) my problem is that if a call is not working (maybe wrong credentials or some other reasons) I can not read out the statusText from backend to show some information to the user. (Because statusText is always undefined)